# How to convert from SWF to HTML5 and transfer to IPAD?

Tags: html5, flash, ipad

I made an Interactive animation by using Flash. But my clients wants an HTML version. And all they need is to play it in IPAD. My question is, Does anybody know how convert from SWF to HTML5 and transfer to IPAD? The file size is like 30MB.

Comment: Did you check [this](https://developers.google.com/swiffy/convert/upload) for converting SWF to HTML5?

Comment: Similar Question in SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885690/swf-to-html5-or-ipad-compatible-format

Comment: This question is most likely just going to result in [recommendations for external sites and resources](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), which has since been deemed off-topic for this site due to issues with spam and self-promotion. The question marked as a duplicate may be helpful, and it's easy enough to do a search for both on and offline tools too.